# View pops from navigation controller stack when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have a popover view which is simply a stack of UIButtons.

The popover is presented from a view controller (Records) which is itself inside a NavigationController.

I need the buttons in popover view to be able to push other views on top of the navigation stack.
Here's how I prepare the segue for the popover in the Records view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
            let dest = segue.destination as! PopoverViewController
            dest.navController = navigationController
            dest.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            dest.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = addButton
            dest.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Then inside the popoverViewController I got a bunch of IBAction functions where I need to push other views on top of the `navController` that was set above.

```
let editor = EditorViewController(nibName: "EditorViewController", bundle: nil)
navController?.pushViewController(editor, animated: true)
```

This kina works and the editor view shows up with a nav bar and all, but as soon as I tap on the view or try to scroll, it just gets dismissed.

How can I prevent that dismiss thing? I did try setting `isModalInPresentation`. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Your "popover" controller should tell the controller that presented it to push the new controller onto the stack. Yo can do this with either protocol/delegate pattern or with closures. However, you say the newly pushed controller *"gets dismissed"*? Do you mean tapping on it or trying to scroll "pops" it back to your Records controller?

Comment: @DonMag Thank you! it worked!

Comment: @DogMag if you could post that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering, as per OP's comments...

The proper approach is to have your "popover" controller tell the *presenting* controller to push a new VC onto the navigation stack.

This can be done in a few different ways, but most commonly by using either the protocol/delegate pattern or with closures.